# Set Google Chrome media cache size

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cache, media, browser-cache

I'm streaming images and videos from my server, with a player that loops over them.

Since thoose files can be very large, i need my client to load them from cache when the player plays more time the same media, but i can't figure out how to force it.

I'm running Google Chrome with

```
--disk-cache-size=5000000000
--media-cache-size=5000000000
--disk-cache-dir="C:\chrome_cache"
```

of course the folder exists, but looking at media in network tab, it looks like the browser downloads every media again and again and again....

Is there a solution to really force the cache size? Looking at the image aboce, it's seems to me that currently it's not using the 5GB i setted as limit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache has a maximum size of 2147483647 bytes that is 2*1024**3-1 or 2GB less a byte. Any size above that is ignored and the default size is used.